# Is this the right way to store tracking information for a website?

Tags: mysql, google-analytics, web-analytics

I need to store the *IP address*, the *User-Agent* of the client who is requesting a particular web page, the *name of the webpage* being requested and the *request time*. I am planning to store the information in a table in the database(MySQL). But, the problem I can for-see is that every time the page is requested there will be a database entry, and in time it would take up a huge amount of space.

Does analytics tools like Google Analytics already store these information (`IP-Address`, `User-Agent`, `Requested-Webpage-Name`, `Time`) that I can access anytime in future (Say, i need to check the client's IP and User-Agent who viewed a particular page within a particular timeframe)? If not, is my approach the right way to do it? If not, what is the right way?

Answer (score 0):

I found that nginx does this out of the box with it's access logs, which are stored in `/var/logs/nginx/access.log`. So, i just need to pare the access log data, using various tools available online.